# don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server

Tags: php, apache

### Access forbidden!

---

Access forbidden!

```
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

localhost
 11/09/11 14:17:57
 Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
```

---

```
<html>
<head><title>Send Self</title></head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] ?>">
<input type="text" value="hello" name="user_data"/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>


<?php
    echo $_POST['user_data'];
?>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your Apache site config? The PHP probably isn't relevant - user permissions for the Apache user on the file you're trying to access are probably the issue